# how to detect ads in website content which are above the fold using php or node.js

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, seo, ads

I need to crawl a website and detect how many ads are on a page.  I've crawled using PHPCrawl and saved the content to DB. How can I detect if a web page has ads above the fold?

Comment: what do you mean by "fold" exactly? It's not a technical term AFAIK. Is it some sort of SEO jargon? How would it relate in terms of a HTML document which you might be trying to parse. P.S. It's worth noting that many ads may be loaded via scripts and/or AJAX after the main page has loaded, and therefore simply requesting a page using something like cURL may not enable you to detect them. You might need a more sophisticated system e.g. a headless browser or software normally designed for GUI testing so it can act more like a regular browser (with JS environment etc).

Comment: Above the fold, as it applies to Web design, is the portion of a Web page that is visible in a browser window when the page first loads. The portion of the page that requires scrolling in order to see content is called "below the fold."

Comment: Ok. Well you cannot possibly know that from a web scrape. That portion will be different for every user depending on screen size etc. The HTML document by itself does not tell you that information, it's entirely contextual to each user and their browser session. Even if you used a more sophisticated method as I mentioned above, with a tool which defined a viewport and made it possible to know what's visible and what's not, any data you collect would still be specific to that session and that viewport size. So you'd have to repeat the test with several "common" viewport sizes to get useful info

Comment: (Also to add to that, even if you assumed everyone had the same screen/viewport size, the scraped HTML document alone still cannot tell you what you're after, because you'd have to combine with with CSS and render it before you'd know, and also because modern web pages commonly load additional content using scripts, which may affect the layout, you're almost certainly not seeing the full content or final layout anyway.)

Comment: You're right. Does it mean that this task is not achievable ?

Comment: I think it's a) very very difficult, and b) even if it's achievable, it's more complex in terms of the data collection requirements than you had anticipated. What was supposed to be the purpose of doing this task in the first place, out of interest?

Comment: In a nutshell, if you are overloading ads above the fold on your websites, you could be in [trouble](https://www.nichepursuits.com/too-many-ads-above-the-fold-time-to-change/). If I can detect that, my system will want to advise the website owners about it.

Comment: Just worth noting perhaps that the google blog on which that article bases itself is about 8 years old. Are you sure they haven't changed things again since then? Google moves pretty fast. And mobile has become a **far** bigger factor than it was in 2012, so does it even make sense to talk about "above the fold" any more? Here's a much more recent analysis: https://www.impactbnd.com/blog/is-staying-above-the-fold-still-relevant-in-website-design (among several similar ones). What I'm trying to say is, I'm not sure this tool you're proposing is going to be a profitable business venture.

Comment: Also worth noting that less than 1% of sites are generally affected by it, so again, it's going to be hard for you to find lots of people who need to take note of it. And, since you don't actually know how google determines this in detail, even if you could relatively easily build the tool you're proposing, you've no real way of knowing whether it will correctly identify the same sites that google would. So you could easily end up giving people incorrect advice.

Answer (score 3):

Well simply put: You can't really. At least not in a simple way. There is many things to consider here and all of them are highly subjective to the web page you are crawling, the device used, etc. I'll try to explain some of the main issues you would need to work around.

**Dynamic Content**

The first big problem is, that you just have the HTML structure, which on itself gives no direct visual information. It would be, if we were in like 1990, but modern websites use CSS and JS to enhance their pages core structure. What you see in your browser is not just HTML rendered as is. It's subject to CSS styling and even JS induced code fragments, which can alter the page significantly. For example: Any page that has a so called AJAX loader, will output as a very simple HTML code block, that you would see in the crawler. But the real page is loaded AFTER this is rendered (from JS).

**Viewport**

What you described as "above the fold" is an arbitary term, that can't be defined globaly. A smartphone has a very different viewport than a desktop PC. Also most of modern websites use a very different structure for mobile, tablet and desktop devices. But let's say you just want to do it for desktop devices. You could define an average viewport over most used screen resolutions (which you may find on the internet). We will define it as 1366x786 for now (based on a quick google search). However you still only have a PHP script and an HTML string. Which brings us the next problem.

**Rendering**

What you see in your browser is actually the result of a complex system, that incooperates HTML and all of the linked ressouces to render a visual representation of the code you have crawled. Besides the core structure of the HTML string you got, any resource linked can (and will) chanfge how the content looks. They can even add more content based on a variety of conditions. So what you would need to get the actual visual information is a so called "headless browser". Only this can give you valid informations about what is actually visible inside the desired viewport. If you want to dig into that topic, a good starting point would be a distribution like "PhantomJS". However don't assume that this is an easy task. You still only have bits of data, no context whatsoever.

**Context, or "What is an ad?"**

Let's assume you have tackled all these problems and made a script that can actually interpret all the things you got from your crawler. You still need to know "What is an ad?". And thats a huge problem. Of course for you as a human it's easy to distinquish between what is part of the website and what is an ad. But translating that into code is more of an AI task than just a basic script. For example: The ads could (and are most of the time) loaded into a predfined container, after the actual page load. These in turn may only have a cryptic ID set that distinguishes them from the rest of the (actually valid) page content. If you are lucky, it has a class with a string like "advertisment", but you can't just define that as given. Ads are subject to all sorts of ad blockers, so they have a long history of trying to disquise themselves as good as possible. You will have a REALLY hard time figuring out what is an ad, and what is valid page content.

So, while I only tackled some of the problems you are going to run into, I want to say that it's not impossible. But you have to understand that you are at the most basic entry point and if you want to make a system that is actually working, you'll have to spend a LOT of time on finetuning and maybe even research on the AI field.

And to come back to your question: There is no simple answer for "How to detect if a page has ads". Because it is way more complex than you might think. Hope this helps.